# Can't output my own data type (* No instance for (Show Ops) arising from a use of `print')

Tags: haskell

I have the following data type :

```
data Ops = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Mod
```

And this function :

```
charToOp :: Char -> Ops
charToOp x 
      | x == '+' = Add
      | x == '-' = Sub
      | x == '*' = Mul
      | x == '/' = Div
      | x == '%' = Mod
```

In GHCI, if I try  `charToOp '+'` I get the following message :

```
*** No instance for (Show Ops) arising from a use of `print'
    * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it**.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

There is no `Show` instance for your data type, try adding the following:

```hs
data Ops = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Mod deriving (Show)
```

now it works:

```hs
*Main> charToOp '-'
Sub
```

Besides, you can also create your own `Show` instance

Sidenote: You can use pattern matching instead of the guards

```hs
charToOp :: Char -> Ops
charToOp x = case x of
    '+' -> Add
    '-' -> Sub
    '*' -> Mul
    '/' -> Div
    '%' -> Mod
```